# JS String has length n, but only n-1 characters. Using str = str.slice(0,-1)

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I am using Khan Academy's webpage in order to make a javascript project (which you can see [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/infix-to-postfix/4666920526741504)). I brought that up because I don't know if the problem is due to a subtlety of javascript, or if it is due to Khan Academy's system.

Here is a description of the problem:

```
var keyPressed = function() {
    if (keyCode === BACKSPACE) {
        debug(textBuffer.length);
        debug(textBuffer);
        textBuffer = textBuffer.slice(0,-1);
    }
};
```

This code will, essentially, be run whenever I press the backspace key. When I invoke the code the *first* time, it works fine; the last character is removed from my global variable `textBuffer`. However, any subsequent calls to this code do nothing to my `textBuffer` string, unless `textBuffer` was changed in between calls. By using `debug` statements, I have noticed that the string length appears to be one too big.

I hope I have provided enough details for someone to sniff out the problem. Does anyone what is going on?

EDIT: Here is the source of the problem: although `keyPressed` is correctly registering the backspace, there is another function called `keyTyped` that was adding an invisible `'\b'` character into the string. This was how the string *appeared* to have only 2 characters but a length of 3.

Comment: `.trim()` or check if there are any invisible characters.

Comment: I have never heard of invisible characters, and a cursory google search didn't turn up anything. Can you elaborate?

Comment: OP, the code here is insufficient to deduce the problem; but looking at the original code you linked, I believe that on backspace first your `keyPressed` activates, deleting the last character, then your `keyTyped` activates, adding a `U+0008` character (which is, BTW, in general, invisible). You should prevent this effect if backspace is typed.

Comment: This question is clearly some kind of bug elsewhere in the code that I can't find. I wonder if I should simply delete this post?

Comment: @Mahkoe Rather than delete the post, you can edit it to show the part that you think contains the bug.

Comment: `debug( JSON.stringify(textBuffer) );` would reveal to you problematic characters. good luck troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press the backspace key, both the `keyTyped` and `keyPressed` functions are executed. `keyPressed` is executed first, which removes a character, and then `keyTyped` is executed, and adds a character to the string, the [backspace character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm).

In JavaScript, this backspace character actually has an escape character for strings: `'\b'`.

To fix your problem, handle the backspace key in the `keyTyped` function, and don't let it append the `toString` value to the `textBuffer`.

```
var keyTyped = function() {
    if (key.toString() === '\n') {
        parse();
        textBuffer = "";
    }
    if (key.toString() === '\b') {
        textBuffer = textBuffer.slice(0, -1);
    } else {
        textBuffer = textBuffer + key.toString();
    }
};
```

Comment: You were correct that there is a '\b' character added into the string. I would not have found  that myself. This has lead me to a solution to the problem